# put argument inside mathematical function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to plot this function using Matlab:

```
b. 2
() = (3)

m = 1/3
k = 8/3
x =  t.*sin(t*pi*m).*heaviside(-m*pi-t)+t.*cos(k*pi*t).*heaviside(t- 
k*pi)+sin(k*pi*t).*cos(m*pi*t).*(heaviside(t+m*pi)-heaviside(t-k*pi));
```

im trying substituting x with x(t) but when I do the code doesnt run:

```
subs t;

t = -5*pi:pi/100:5*pi;

m = 1/3;

k = 8/3;

x(t) = t.*sin(t*pi*m).*heaviside(-m*pi-t)+t.*cos(k*pi*t).*heaviside(t- 
k*pi)+sin(k*pi*t).*cos(m*pi*t).*(heaviside(t+m*pi)-heaviside(t-k*pi));

x1 = m-x/k;








 plot(t,x1,t,x);
```

Any help?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? you want to plot an array `x`, so there's no need for `x(t)` (which is not valid syntax for this use case), unclear why you're trying to use it and not sticking with your original?

Comment: I have to plot x(3kt) and I was wondering how I can modify my code in order to have a x(t) function valid.